# Proving a Ring is a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a ring with the following property: given any elements $a , c \in R$ with $a \neq 0 $, there exists an element $x \in R$ such that $ax = c$. Show that $R$ is a domain.

I have started by assuming $\alpha, \beta \in R$ are both non zero, and I am trying to show that their product $\alpha \beta \neq 0$ also. From the conditions given in the question, there are $x, y \in R$ such that $\alpha x = \beta$ and $\beta y = \alpha$. However from here I am not sure how to show that $\alpha \beta \neq 0 $.

Comment: Does $R$ have an identity element?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841101/abstract-algebra-division-ring-theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't react to the answer of @Severin Schraven I will try to add a bit more detail to his answer, hoping this helps you, but full credit goes to him. As far as I understand that is how he wants to do it. Let $R \neq (0)$ be a ring with $1$, as well as $a,b \in R \smallsetminus \{0\}$ satisfying $ab=0$. Now let $x \in R$ be arbitrary. Since $b \neq (0)$ your property ensures the existence of an element $d \in R$ such that $x=bd$. We then have $ax=a(bd)=(ab)d=0$ by associativity of the ring and the assumption. Since this holds for all $x \in R$ we have that $1=a1=0$ since by definition of a ring with $1$ we have $1r=r1=r$ for all $r \in R$. This assumes that you mean integral domain by domain.

Comment: It is great that you add more details! Actually, we don't really need that the ring has a unity. Let $c$ be some element in $R$, then there exists $d$ such that $bd=c$ and hence, we get $$ 0=(ab)d= a(bd) = ac $$ hence ,we get that for every $c$ in $R$ that $ac=0$. However, if $R$ is not the zero ring, then there exists some $0\neq e\in R$ and some $c\in R$ such that $0=ac=e$ which is a contradiction :D so the really cool thing is that we need really nothing from our ring (neither commutative, nor unital)! Sorry, got a bit carried away. Anyway, I like your elaboration (+1).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven You're absolutely right, I didn't really see that. I have never worked with non unital rings but as far as I can see you have to use the property the OP gave in order for the implication: "if $ac=0$ for all $c \in R$ we have $R=0$" to work, or am I missing something? Anyways, thank you for adding that.

Comment: I was a bit confusing. I meant, we do not need anything additional to the property the OP gave :) usually things break down, when we remove commutativity or unitality, but here that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is the zero ring, then we are fine (depending on your definition of domain).

Assume now $R$ is not the zero ring. Let $a,b\neq 0$. Assume $ab =0$. Then use your property and associativity of the product to show that for all $c$ holds $ac=0$. Unless $R$ is the zero ring, this would contradict your property.